# Passport.js Multiple login system is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am getting a weird error as all of my login system are working correctly which include local login in system and Google and Facebook login. The problem arose when I try to try to register with google when I have already register the Facebook account and I try to register Google account it gives `E11000 duplicate key error collection` and vice versa for Facebook. I am using `passport.js` for authentication and login system here is some code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStratgy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { static } = require("express");
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    googleId: String,
    facebookId: String
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

/* userSchema.plugin(encrypt,{secret: process.env.SECRET, encryptedFields: ['password']}); */


const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
passport.use(new LocalStratgy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRETS,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
    });
}
));


passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FB_APP_SECRETS,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/secrets"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/" ,(req, res) => {
    res.render('home');

});
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));
  app.get('/auth/google/secrets', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect secrets.
    res.redirect('/secrets');
  });

  app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));
  app.get('/auth/facebook/secrets',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, secrets .
    res.redirect('/secrets');
  });

app.get("/login" ,(req, res) => {
    res.render('login');

});



app.get("/register" ,(req, res) => {
    res.render('register');

});
app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("secrets");
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
})

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        }else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        }
    })

    
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    req.login(user, err => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });
        }
    })

});
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect("/");
})
```

Note: Individually the Facebook and Google authentication works like a charm but when both used together it throws an error. I store Facebook and Google id in my database as in screenshot: [image: Image of database here] and local system works just fine with Facebook and Google no problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow passport documentation then it's probably not so correct *for your usage*.

The following will just create an account base on facebook Id

```
User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
  return cb(err, user);
});
```

The following will just create an account base on google Id

```
User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    return cb(err, user);
});
```

**However**, I'm quite sure your user is **identified by email**.

Your above queries will create **2 separate _id with same email address**.

Hence your query should be corrected to similar as follows

```
 User.updateOne({ email: profile.email }, { googleId: profile.id }, { upsert: true })
```

And

```
 User.updateOne({ email: profile.email }, { facebookId: profile.id }, { upsert: true })
```

The above will check whether email exist, if it does, update googleId. If it doesn't exist, create a new user.

**In addition**, your schema is missing the `username` field